# Is "Didn't used to have been" a valid structure?

Tags: grammar, tenses

Are the following sentences valid:

> It *didn't used to* happen.
>
> It *didn't used to have been* there.

And if so, what tenses are they?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the negation of “I used to be”? Surely not “I didn't used to be”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/whats-the-negation-of-i-used-to-be-surely-not-i-didnt-used-to-be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Didn't used to ..." is a colloquialism (i.e. informal) combining "didn't" and "used to" and both are past tense, like a double negative. And like a double negative, it's not wrong, just not formal. In fact both forms are common and informal.

See http://thestar.com.my/english/story.asp?file=/2007/11/9/lifefocus/19384883&sec=lifefocus

It is used quite often by many people, including journalists:

http://www.jsonline.com/news/opinion/102182784.html

http://www.stuhenderson.com/21RACFS.pdf

By the way, although Google NGrams can be misused, I think a direct comparison here using that tool is informative here.

[image: didn't used to vs. didn't use to]

It shows that both terms are used and that "didn't used to" has gained ascendancy over the latter half of the 20th century.

Comment: Why didn't you search earlier? I searched from 1750, and "didn't used to" was shown up above. Because of the recent rise of informal speech, it doesn't mean "didn't used to" is necessarily correct.

Comment: Thank you. What about "didn't used to have been"? When did that come into being, and what tense would you call that?

Comment: @Urbycoz: Now there I would draw the line. Although you may find instances of that usage, the plain infinitival form is more what you hear, probably because both expressions derive from "used" + *infinitive* (*used to dance*, *used to be*, *used to laugh [about]* and so on).

Comment: It's certainly true NGrams can mislead, but I suggest this link backs up my feeling that *both* variations are somewhat archaic, and falling into disuse following their Victorian heyday... http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=used+to+have+been%2Cuse+to+have+been&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10

Answer (score 5):

It should be "use", because "did" already makes it past tense, so "-d" is not needed.

"didn't use" is simple past, and "to have been" is an infinitive with the verb a past perfect.

This [graph](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=didn%20%27%20t%20use%20to%2Cdidn%20%27%20t%20used%20to&corpus=0&smoothing=7&year_start=1800&year_end=2000) shows that only recently has "didn't used to" rise in use. This is also characterized with the rise of usage and popularity with many informal and actually incorrect English.

Comment: This is nonsense.

Comment: @Robusto, Why so? Please explain

Comment: See my answer below. Both forms are used informally everywhere you look. In fact, "didn't used to" is even more common than "didn't use to" is.

Comment: That may be so, sir, but I didn't say they were wrong, just not needed.

Comment: You said "should be 'use'"; saying one is "right" is tantamount to saying the other is "wrong". Either words mean something or they don't.

Comment: +1 for this answer, "didn't used to" is so wrong it can't get any wronger.

Comment: I conjecture that the rise of "didn't used to" is because "use to" (as opposed to "used to") ceased to be current.

Comment: I agree with @Third Idiot. Nothing wrong with plain old *weren't*.

Comment: @Robusto, @Colin, actually, I’d say it’s because *didn’t use to* is hard to use in a real sentence. It *sounds* okay on its own, but it does not fit in an actual sentence; you would have to insert an “it” or something: *didn’t use **it** to…*.