# Making question and negative form with "used to"

Tags: verbs

According to the various grammar books that I have read, the question and negative , with "used to" starting with "did" has two forms. One for example is "Did he used to smoke Cigars?" and the other is "Did he use to smoke cigars?".
 I would just like to know which form is correct and widely used.

Comment: [What's the negation of “I used to be”? Surely not “I didn't used to be”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/) [Is “Didn't used to have been” a valid structure?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28369/) [Alternatives to the common construction “didn't used to”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149484/) [Rhetorical questions with “used to”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153823/) and the related questions linked from these.

Answer (score 1):

> **"Did he use to** smoke cigars?"
>
> "Yes, **he did (use to** smoke cigar)." Or "No, he **didn't (use to** smoke cigars)."

"Did he used to" and "he didn't used to" are merely ungrammatical variations.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom is *Used to*.
The formal (British) negative version is *I used not to smoke cigars* but if you want to use did, you need to drop the d as in *Did he use to smoke?*

The *Did use to* is considered informal

http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00074.htm