# What is the proper tense for the negation of "used to"?

Tags: tenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the negation of “I used to be”? Surely not “I didn’t used to be”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/whats-the-negation-of-i-used-to-be-surely-not-i-didnt-used-to-be)

Should I say I "didn't used to" do something? Or "didn't use to"?

Answer (score 1):

The negative of English verbs is formed with the appropriate form of the auxiliary verb *do* followed by *not* (or its contraction) and the plain form of the main verb. *I knew*, for example, becomes *I didn’t know* in the negative.

In the same way, *I used to* becomes *I didn’t use to*. In speech, /d/ is the voiced version of /t/, which means that the /t/ at the beginning of ‘to’ may sometimes be heard, or even pronounced, as /d/, giving the impression that what is being said is *I didn't used to*. In writing, however, it should always appear as *use*.

Answer (score 0):

"I didn't use to" is grammatically correct. Only one element of the main verb can carry the tense marker. If you say *"I didn't used to", two elements are carrying the past tense marker: "didn't" & "used".