# "Did used to" vs. "did use to"

Tags: grammar, colloquialisms

The use of "used to" is much more frequent than "use to", but what about "did used to" vs. "did use to"?

Comment: Could you provide a couple of example quotes where you'd use these phrases?

Comment: The following question is more related: [What's the negation of “I used to be”? Surely not “I didn't used to be”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8816)

Answer (score 6):

I think **did use to** is correct. Confusion over whether to use the form **used to** or **use to**, arises because the pronunciation seems the same in both cases.

Except in negatives and questions, the correct form is **used to**.However, in negatives and questions using the auxiliary verb **do**, the correct form is **use to**, because the form of the verb required is the infinitive.

> So, i think **did use to** would be the correct one to use.