# Didn't you USED TO or Didn't you USE TO?

Tags: meaning, grammar, syntactic-analysis

I was somehow confused encountering this sentence: Didn't you USED TO work with Annie at Macy's?. Should we use USE TO here since we are using Did which needs the base form of the verb.

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30035/i-use-to-or-i-used http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178471/did-used-to-vs-did-use-to

Comment: 'used to' is one way to do the past progressive. The standard way of negating 'used to' would be to 'I never used to X' or 'I stopped Xing' or 'I wasn't Xing'. 'I didn't use(d) to' is non-standard; neither is to be written in formal language (newspapers, school work). SO how it is spelled is not rule based. Either way is as 'correct' as the other because either way is _not_ 'correct'. I'd personally write 'didn't used to' because it's pronounced the same way as the positive. 'didn't use to' might be more logical, but logic doesn't always apply in spelling.

Comment: The duplicate is a much better fit.

Answer (score 0):

It should be **use to**.

Why? Because you're using a **did**(not) in your sentence. The general rule is that when you use 'did' in a sentence, the tense used is *present*.

For example (though in both cases, the intention becomes slightly different due to emphasis)

> *I **did go** to the party.*  vs  *I **went** to the party.*
>
> *You **worked** with Clara* vs *You **did work** with Clara*

Similarly with your example:

> *You **used to** work with Annie, right?* vs *Didn't you **use to** work with Annie?*

Comment: So what's my sin? It would be nice to know the reason for the downvote, otherwise this tells me nothing about what is being 'called out' here.

Comment: Perhaps as a guess for the downvote, it could be your saying that the tense following **did** is in the present. It's not, it's in the bare infinitive. Furthermore,  in speech the negative tense *didn't use to* is identical to  the affirmative form *I used to" with the addition of "didn't" in front.

Answer (score -4):

***Used*** is the correct form because it is past tense.The phrase *used to,* in this instance, refers to  a past action or condition.

Comment: This may be common usage, but it would be considered grammatically incorrect by many. "Didn't used" is not how a past tense form would normally be negated; _used to_ is abnormal.

Comment: I checked in a grammar book and it should be written this  DIDN'T USE TO and not DIDN"T USED TO.

Comment: Okay, @Janus Bahs Jacqet, I stand corrected.