# Is there any phrase 'use to" in english

Tags: phrases

phrase use to I want to know is there any phrase use to in english if yes then how to use it

Comment: possible duplicate of ["I use to", or "I used to"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30035/i-use-to-or-i-used-to). Note that [in some constructions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178747/didnt-you-used-to-or-didnt-you-use-to#comment372784_178747) there's no definitive consensus on whether it should be spelled ***use*** or ***used*** (it being an orthographic distinction that can't always be made in speech, and the grammar/tense issue is murky, to say the least).

Comment: Do you mean the phrase *[used to](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/used+to)*?

Comment: You might be very interested in checking out this community as well: [ell.se].

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you might use this construction in cases like:

> This is my car, which I *use to* get to work.

However, I suspect that what you're really thinking of is the phrase "[used to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30035/i-use-to-or-i-used-to)."

Answer (score 0):

"used to" + the infnitive expresses an imperfect past tense. "Used to" + gerund is equivalent to "accustomed to". The two are completely separate in meaning.