# Tag question with 'used to be'

Tags: question-tags, used-to

I cannot find any resources online for tag question with the phrase *used to be*. I'm looking for something that can give the rules for this example, *He used to be handsome, didn't/wasn't he?*

Comment: The negative of _used to_ is _didn't used to_, so the tag would be ", didn't he?"

Comment: @JohnLawler: I agree, but wouldn't that be written as ["didn't use to"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/whats-the-negation-of-i-used-to-be-surely-not-i-didnt-used-to-be)?

Comment: Thanks, Lawler. If you can make it into an answer I can give you best answer and they can close the question.

Comment: No, _Used to_ is a fixed phrase past tense idiom that must be followed by an infinitive. So it requires _Do_-Support for negation. I admit it doesnt look right spelled that way, but it doesnt look good the other way, either.

Comment: @John Lawler << Negative: **didn’t use to**
The negative of _used to_ is most commonly _didn’t use(d) to_. Sometimes we write it with a final -d, sometimes not. Both forms are common, but many people consider the form with the final -d to be incorrect, and you should not use it in exams:

_It didn’t use to be so crowded in the shops as it is nowadays._ // 

_I didn’t used to like broccoli when I was younger, but I love it now._ (Don’t use this form in exams.) >> [[English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/used-to)]

Comment: Typical that exams deal only with trivialities like spelling and "correctness" instead of real language.

Answer (score 1):

The correct ending would be "didn't he?" Used to pairs with didn't (as in "didn't used to be").

Answer (score 0):

In comments, John Lawler and Edwin Ashforth wrote:

> - **John**: The negative of *used to* is *didn't used to*, so the tag would be ", didn't he?"

> - **John**: No, *Used to* is a fixed phrase past tense idiom that must be followed by an infinitive. So it requires *Do*-Support for negation. I admit it doesnt look right spelled that way, but it doesnt look good the other way, either.

> - **Edwin**: @John Lawler
>
> > << Negative: **didn’t use to**
> > The negative of *used to* is most commonly *didn’t use(d) to*. Sometimes we write it with a final -d, sometimes not. Both forms are common, but many people consider the form with the final -d to be incorrect, and you should not use it in exams:
> >
> > *It didn’t use to be so crowded in the shops as it is nowadays.* //
> >
> > *I didn’t used to like broccoli when I was younger, but I love it now.* (Don’t use this form in exams.) >>
>
> [[English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/used-to)]

> - **John**: Typical that exams deal only with trivialities like spelling and "correctness" instead of real language.