My father was an English teacher and he taught us to say 'usen't' He considered 'didn't use(d) to' incorrect.Strange how usage takes over, eg snuck
'Didn't use(d)' to jars with me even though many people use it.I'm certainly not posh and neither was my father.

Is there a question you wanted to ask? If so, you should edit it in.

There are several other questions on this.

... and also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/whats-the-negation-of-i-used-to-be-surely-not-i-didnt-used-to-be - there is little objection to "used not to" as the opposite of "used to", and it avoids the issue of whether "usedn't" and "usen't" are acceptable.
