# What is the question form of "used to do"?

Tags: verbs, questions

What is the correct way to convert "used to do" into a question? Since I want to emphasize that the action is not on-going any more, so simple past tense is not a good idea here. Could I say "do xxx use to do" or "did xxx use to do"? Both sound weird to me.

If there is no way to do it. Do you suggest any other alternatives?

Comment: Related: [How does the phrase “used to” work, grammatically?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128/) and [I didn't used to be?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, most of your doubts would be retracted after reading up http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_used-to-do.htm

I would like to summarize the main points from the webpage.

1) We use the used to do expression to talk about:
 - an activity that we did regularly in the past (like a habit)
 - a situation that was true in the past

For example,

> He used to watch a lot of TV.
>
> They used to be married.

2) Used or use?
 - when there is did in the sentence, we say use to (without d)
 - when there is no did in the sentence, we say used to (with d)

For example,

> Did you use to smoke?
>
> I didn't use to go swimming.

Answer (score 8):

In principle, there's not much reason to think that the construction isn't perfectly regular, and you will find the following used:

> Didn't they **use** to come here often?

But phonetically, "use to" and "used to" are practically indistinguishable and almost certainly not *reliably* distinguishable. In practice, you will see the following more commonly written down:

> Didn't they **used** to come here often?

In speech, it's not really clear what percentage of people are 'really' saying **use** and what percentage are saying **used**.

The following slightly archaic forms also exist:

> Used they to help you?
>
> Used they not to help you?
>
> Usen't they to help you?

Of these, **usen't they** is also used to form tags (albeit not so commonly as other forms such as **didn't they**, **wouldn't they** etc).

Comment: To anyone studying English who finds this confusing: They are *so* “practically indistinguishable” that even a native speaker of English can go through a significant portion of their life without realizing that the tense changes. (I didn't use to notice the difference.) As for *why* it changes - this is simply to avoid a double past tense. “Didn't used to” would be incorrect for the same grammatical reason “didn't went” would be. It's just one of those things you'll need to get used to.

Answer (score -1):

You could just cut out the "used" entirely.

"What did you do?" It sounds much more natural, than used to, despite used to technically being grammatically valid. It may not work with what you are trying to use it for, but it's another option.

Comment: "What did you do?" does not mean the same thing as "What did you used to do?". With "used to" (or use to) it refers to an action that occurred more than once in the past but no longer occurs.

Answer (score -1):

How about

> What did you do previously?

Comment: "What did you do" is a single event. "Previously" makes no difference.

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty simple:

> What did you used to do?
>
> What was it we used to do when Barney and his friends came over?
>
> Did you used to do anything that could get you into trouble?
>
> Did Marcia ever used to do anything so silly?

Comment: Robusto, Did and Used to don't sound that well together. I'm not very sure, is the construct grammatically correct?

Comment: It is the way I used it. Bonuse anecdote: Will Rogers, a homespun humorist of the early 20th century, would say things like "we used to dident (sic) ..." But although he was a brilliant satirist, he didn't need correct grammar for his act to work. In fact, correct grammar would have worked against him.

Comment: +1 But really, it would be great if could confirm it's correctness with the grammar.

Comment: Confirm grammar? That's the sort of thing I used to do. Not anymore! :) Seriously, check the question again. I went out of my way and brought you a link.

Comment: *when there is did in the sentence, we say use to (without d) 
*when there is no did in the sentence, we say used to (with d) So you can edit your answer.

Comment: and -1 for not reading up your link before posting it up.

Comment: Your examples #1, #3 and #4 are directly contradicted by the example in your link: "Did you use to smoke?" Read the EnglishClub tip box.