# Asking a Question in the Imperfect

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I can say in Spanish,

> Yo jugaba al tenis cuando tenía 8 años,

which means

> I used to play tennis when I was 8 years old.

I could also ask,

> ¿Jugabas tú al tenis cuando tenías 8 años?

whose English counterpart is

> Did you play tennis when you were 8 years old?

Sometimes I get stuck, though, since it's hard to ask

> Did you *use to* play tennis ...

Is there a real way to ask a question in the imperfect using the "used to" form of the imperfect?

Comment: Yes, there is, but it's only spoken. As you point out, _use to_ and _used to_ are pronounced identically, so there's no problem with **saying** it. But there's no accepted way to **spell** it. _Did you use to_ looks funny, and _Did you used to_ looks ungrammatical. The fact that they're pronounced the same is lost on those who believe the written language is the principal source, so they have lots of trouble. But native speakers just go on talking; mostly they can't spell, anyway.

Comment: @Johnlawler *Did you use to* only looks funny to them because they don't read anything written before ten o'clock this morning. Maybe they can't ...

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16480/what-is-the-question-form-of-used-to-do