# Usage of 'USED TO' : part 2.different than existing question

Tags: word-usage

Another question about `used to` does exist [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16480/what-is-the-question-form-of-used-to-do). But this question is slightly different. It concerns with two types.

Which is more appropriate?

First, `doing` or `do`?

Second, `were` or `did`?

Which of the following types of usage is/are correct?

> ----Were you `used to doing` this
>
> or----Were you `used to do` this?
>
> ----`Did` you use to....
>
> or ---`Were` you used to... (as above)

Please give a detailed explanation.

Comment: I edited this question! Does this still seem that 'duplicate'? @RegDwigHt

Comment: It may not be a duplicate anymore, but it is still off-topic as General Reference.

Comment: General Reference? Sorry. Didn't get you well. How exactly is it off-topic? It concerns English usage here, doesn't it?

Comment: You're confusing at least two different constructions. (a) I used to play golf = I was in the habit of playing golf. (b) I was used to hitting drives into the lake = I depressingly often hit drives / was accustomed to hitting drives into the lake. (c) A sand wedge is used to chip out of bunkers = A sand wedge is employed to chip out of bunkers.