# What's the proper and formal way of asking "Didn't we used to do ..."?

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense, register

I saw it used in an article online, and it doesn't seem proper to me because of the two past tenses used together. But since "use to" can't be used here, I don't know what would be the proper way.

Care to comment please? Thanks.

[EDIT] The answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/whats-the-negation-of-i-used-to-be-surely-not-i-didnt-used-to-be) says that "Didn't we use to do ..." is informal and not widely accepted. So what would be the formal way of phrasing it?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. See e.g. [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8816/), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/128/), or the many related questions linked from these. Please use the site search before asking.

Comment: But neither of the questions answer to what is the proper way to ask "Didn't we use to do ...". [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/…) only says the format is informal.

Comment: If you don't want to say *"Didn't we use(d) to"* because you think it's informal, you have to rephrase it entirely: *"Didn't we use to be a delivery company?"* would become something like *"Weren't we once a delivery company?"*

Comment: Since the OP asks for the "formal" way of rephrasing it, I would not consider the question a clear duplicate.  Although I do say "we didn't use to..." a gazillion times a year, and recognize it as grammatical, I would not write *The Senate didn't use to follow this rule, whereby....* because "didn't use to" isn't in the same register as "whereby".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But since "use to" can't be used here,

Who has told you that?

> We didn't use to go swimming a lot, but now we love it.

Is just fine. After a *supporting do* we use an *infinitive*, not a conjugated verb.

Any google search for *didn't we use to* will find you articles about this, like for example this one from [LearnEnglish](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/usedtotext.html):

> Did you use to go out with my sister?
>   Did they use to own the company?
>   Didn't we use to go to the same school?

Basically *use* behaves the same way that any verb does when we switch to do-support: (for completeness, we only look at the simple past here because of the idiomatic usage of *use*).

> He **walked** to school. -->*walked in simple past*
>   He didn't **walk** to school. -->*supporting **do** in simple past + infinitive*
>   He **used** to walk to school. -->*used in simple past*
>   He didn't **use** to walk to school. -->*supporting **do** in simple past + infinitive*

---

All that said, in the linked topic it is shown that *I didn't used to*, although grammatically baffling, has been gaining popularity, probably because of the similar pronunciation. So people decided to always write *used* without having to think about it.

That we end up with a sentence with to conjugated verbs for one subject in one clause, soit. We need exceptions, right? :)

Comment: Oh. Don't remember where, but I did read somewhere that only "used to" gives it that meaning. And you're  saying _use_ behaves the same way as verbs, but doesn't _to_ go along with _use_ here? So, does _used to_ behave the same way as other verbs?

Comment: @shyam _To_ is just a preposition that happens to form a common collocation with _use_. _Use_ behave exactly like _walk_. If you insist on looking at the whole collocation thing, you can, but the preposition does not change anything, so why bother? Take for example _believe in_: _I believed in miracles_ -> _I didn't believe in miracles_. You just conjugate _one_ verb, so when you use supporting _do_, _that's_ the verb you conjugate and teh main verb stays in the infinitive.

Comment: However, The answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/whats-the-negation-of-i-used-to-be-surely-not-i-didnt-used-to-be) says "Didn't we *use to* ..." is informal and not widely accepted. So what would be a proper and formal way to phrase it?

Comment: @shyam The most upvoted answer there provides you with _I used not to ..._ However, there is a very interesting ngram in another answer there that shows that my answer may be completely wrong when it comes to actual usage :|

Comment: It's not true that *used to* conjugates like other verbs. For the future, for a normal verb you would change *I took* to *I will take*. For *I used to*, you cannot say *I will use to*. But you are allowed to say *I didn't use to* (often spelled *I didn't used to*).

Comment: Where the heck did "use to" come from?  (Texting?) It is ALWAYS "used to".

Comment: @PeterShor: Sorry, I will add the context: **in the simple past**, when switching to do-support. I thought the implication was clear as that was what the question was about :)

Comment: @Oldbag: _I didn't use to_ is the ONLY form that follows from simple application of basic grammar. The big question is, where the heck did _I didn't used to_ come from, since it is the only case where I see two verbs being conjugated for only one subject. And the answer, as discussed in the other topic, is probably that people felt the two sounded the same so they decided to write _used_ so they didn't have to think about it too much.

Comment: Since when? (Seriously) We were taught that "used to" was correct. (Were my teachers wrong... or has it changed?)

Comment: @Oldbag: teachers are very often wrong, so that should certainly be kept as a possibility. As to "since when", in _every_ clause we have a maximum of one verb conjugated to fit the subject, never two. This would be the only exception to that rule I am aware of. If you just use _basic rules for conjugation_, _I didn't use to_ is the _only_ option that makes sense. Popularity of the "let's not think about it and just write _used_ whenever"-idea has somehow made _I didn't used to_ a part of the language, but _that_ is what puzzles me, not why one day people applied basic grammar :)